# Error Getting While Executing Query On Hive Tables in WSo2

Tags: hadoop, wso2, wso2-esb

I am getting below error while executing any query (except select * from table) on hive tables in WSO2 . Please suggest

Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

is there something , I am missing in configuration of BAM .

Answer (score 0):

You want to go to the JobTracker UI (port 50030 on the JobTracker machine). Find the failed job that matches your query and look for errors in the job log.

The Hive error just says the job failed, you need to know what error caused that failure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Can you describe in more details that I how can use Job Tracker UI .

Comment: Its a GUI :) go to HTTP://<job tracker ip>:50030. Click on a job, click on a map task, click on "logs"...